# npm run dev | npm start

Tags: heroku, npm-start, npm-run

My application will run when I start with "npm run dev" in the terminal. But when I enter "npm start" it says, ERR start no found.

So, I created a procfile and added exactly web: npm run dev and pushed it to heroku and it is not running.

Comment: You created a `procfile` or you created a _`Procfile`?_ Those are different names, and Heroku wants to the the latter.

Comment: (Side note: You probably shouldn't be running `npm run dev` on Heroku. That likely runs some kind of build-on-the-fly process that might watch for filesystem changes and reload, etc. In production, you should be running a different stack. It's likely better to define appropriate `build` and `start` scripts.)